# Android fail to import library

Tags: android, gradle

I am new to Android development and making simple app using Jetpack Compose thesedays.

When I import a library in an empty Jetpack Compose project, the compiler can't find the package path.

```
import me.aflak.arduino.Arduino
import me.aflak.arduino.ArduinoListener
```

**Error message: Unresolved reference: me**

This library works fine for "normal View" project. I already googled but couldn't find a clear answer for it.
I doulble checked that I didn't change any settings but for library include.

I really want to know why it fails to import.

Thanks

Here's the build.gradle (Module)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.composewitharduino"
        minSdk 23
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"

    implementation 'me.aflak.libraries:arduino:1.4.5'
}
```

Comment: Can you add your build.gradle with the `implementation ...` for this library?

Comment: @MarioHuizinga I added build.gradle. Please check it. :)

Comment: Seems fine, I have no idea what's wrong.

Comment: I had similar problem once and it was fixed by "Invalidate caches and restart"

Answer (score 1):

Add these lines into `settings.gradle`

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
   // THESE LINES NEED TO BE ADDED
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
}
```